# PUT/POST Rest api calls not working while trying from AngularJS in Java

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am new to AngularJS.

I am getting an error while trying to call PUT restful webservices from AngularJS. This is my factory method.

```
.factory('EmployeeService',function($q,$http){
    Approval:function(userId,firstName){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: '/AngularExample/user',
    params:{
    lastName:userId,
    firstName:firstName
    }
    }).
    success(function (data) {

    if (data != null || data != 'undefined') {

    deferred.resolve( data);


    }
    })
    .error(function (error) {

    console.log('error');
    });
    return deferred.promise;

    })
```

EmployeeService is my service name

```
 $scope.showAlert = function () {
    EmployeeService.Approval( $stateParams.userId,$stateParams.firstName).then(function (approval) {
    $scope.approve= approval;
    })
```

This is the error getting while calling PUT REST Api call in Java.

```
 Angular JS version using :1.3.15 . 
 Rest api call is not triggering from angular to Rest Back end and not getting any error in back End.
 Error getting in the angular js :
      unexpected Request PUT No more request expected
                           at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1180)
                           at m (angular.js:9628)
                           at $get.f (angular.js:9344)
                           at angular.js:13189
                           at l.$get.l.$eval (angular.js:14401)
                           at l.$get.l.$digest (angular.js:14217)
                           at l.$get.l.$apply (angular.js:14506)
                           at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic-angular.js:9958)
                           at HTMLButtonElement.c (angular.js:3014)
                           at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.js:2804)
```

It works in Postman.

Comment: web services is working in postman rest client in chrome

Comment: Have you tried adding the complete url of the service instead of /AngularExample/user ?

Comment: Are you including angular-mocks in your HTML? Don't do that

Comment: Added complete url of the restful  service

Answer (score 0):

```
    i am using service and simple call the our REST API
//in app/js
var serverUrl = 'http://xxxxx.in/api';
.service('UserBankDetails', ['$http',
        function($http) {
            this.userBankDetailsAdd = function(data, cb) {
                var res = $http.put(serverUrl + "/user_bank_account", data);
                res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    cb(data);
                });
            }
        }
    ])
    //simple call from controller
UserBankDetails.userBankDetailsAdd($scope.userBankInfo, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.data === 1) {
        $scope.account_found = true;
    } else {
        $scope.account_found = false;
    }
});
```